# Different answers when attempting replacement of function argument

Tags: functions, replacement

I have three function computing Fibonacci numbers which return correct answers when directly called with e.g. `fib1[10]`:

```
fib1[n_] := Nest[{#[[2]], #[[1]] + #[[2]]} &, {0, 1}, n - 1] // Last

fib2[n_] := Module[{a = 0, b = 1, q},
  If[n == 0, Return[0]]; 
     bits = IntegerDigits[n, 2]; 
     Do[{a, b} = {a^2 + b^2, b (2 a + b)}; 
     If[bits[[q]] != 0, 
        {a, b} = {b, a + b}], 
        {q, 2, Length[bits]}]; 
     Return[b] 
]

fib3[n_] := Round[(((1 + Sqrt[5])/2)^n - ((1 - Sqrt[5])/2)^n)/Sqrt[5]]
```

However, if I try to execute them like this:

```
{fib1[n], fib2[n], fib3[n], Fibonacci[n]} /. n -> 10
```

I expect to obtain

```
{55, 55, 55, 55}
```

But in instead, I obtain:

```
{9, 2, 55, 55}
```

with a warning : [image: Nest: non negative machine integer expected]

(The warning seems to be related to the evaluation of the function `fib1`)

Why do `fib1` and `fib2` return an incorrect answer whereas `fib3` and Fibonacci returns the right answer in the replacement case?

Comment: For your `fib3` use `fib3[n_] := (((1/2)*(1 + Sqrt[5]))^n - (2/(1 + Sqrt[5]))^n*Cos[n*Pi])/ Sqrt[5]` then it is valid for all `n`. You can get this from `Fibonacci[n] // FunctionExpand`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/.` infix form is just syntactic sugar. The expression that gets evaluated here is

```
ReplaceAll[{fib1[n], fib2[n], fib3[n], Fibonacci[n]}, n -> 10]
```

There's nothing profound in showing that, but hopefully it makes clear that the arguments must be evaluated before the overall expression can be evaluated. Some functions have various `Hold*` attributes which allow them to subvert the normal order of evaluation, but `ReplaceAll` isn't one of those. Thus, the first argument will be fully evaluated before the `n->10` rule gets applied. When the rule does eventually get applied, it gets applied to this expression:

```
{-1 + n, 2, Round[(-((1 - Sqrt[5])/2)^n + ((1 + Sqrt[5])/2)^n)/Sqrt[5]], Fibonacci[n]}
```

So, to answer your question about how `ReplaceAll` works, there's nothing special going on here. We're just churning through the evaluation process.

To answer the implied question of how this kind of operation should be done, I would suggest this:

```
Through[{fib1, fib2, fib3, Fibonacci}[10]]
```

The concept of "applying several functions to the same argument" has already been thought of and implemented by the Wolfram team, and so you might as well take advantage of it.

Answer (score 4):

`fib1` should be limited not to evaluate unless $n$ is an explicit integer number, so let's redefine it as such (in the following I've also used a version with numbered slots and `Apply` that looks more readable to me):

```
ClearAll[fib1]
fib1[n_Integer?Positive] := Nest[Apply[{#2, #1 + #2} &], {0, 1}, n - 1] // Last

{fib1[n]} /. n -> 10
(* Out: {55} *)
```

You should do the same with `fib2` as well.

Comment: The definition should be restricted to positive integers since `Nest` must be given a nonnegative argument, i.e., `fib1[n_Integer?Positive] := ...`

Comment: @BobHanlon Good point. I added that too. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Look at:

```
fib1[n]

-1 + n

fib1[n] /. n->10

9
```

And for fib2:

```
fib2[n]

2
```

Here the ReplaceAll does nothing.

Comment: is there a way (i tried with RuleDelayed with no success) to ask Mathematica to evaluate fib etc after the replacement?

Comment: @youyou Yes. See my answer below.

Comment: btw I obtain the good behavior by changing fib1[n_] to fib1[n_Integer], but i'd like also to understand how ReplaceAll works

Comment: @youyou I think the part about ReplaceAll is well addressed in Daniel's answer. First, `fib1` was evaluated evaluation to return $n-1$; then `ReplaceAll` operates on that result by replacing $n$ with 10; then 10-1 is evaluated to return 9.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` does the job as well:

```
Hold[{fib1[n], fib2[n], fib3[n], Fibonacci[n]}] /. n -> 10 // ReleaseHold
```